# Can I represent matrix using JSON.(Multidimensional Array)

Tags: json, multidimensional-array, n-queens

Can I represent matrix using JSON. I have to take position of queen on chess board using in 8 queens problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. According to [JSON.org](http://json.org/) you can include value in array and array in value, so it means you can write nested arrays.